# What is a word for someone who has multiple skills/talents?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the title for someone who has multiple talents and skills? Eg, juggling, pickpocketing, memory expert, sleight of hand etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Although, for most of your examples, [prestidigitator](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prestidigitator) seems more apt.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to stay away from things that a magic/magician based and more to do with skill itself.

Comment: Some of the answers in the other thread are very formal...sort of a dilemma here with this site as often the most accurate word would only be used conversationally by people with far above average educations...or older people.  I'd say conversationally saying "John's good at everything" or "A multi-talented guy"  comes across more conversationally than calling someone a "Renaissance man" .. which would have been the way to put in in writing 30 years ago for sure(and perhaps even today).

Comment: Note that I voted to close not as a duplicate, but because the question is not clear about how the word is to be used. If you edit to show the usage as referring specifically someone who is manually dexterous (prestidigitator per @Davo), then I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

A person who has many skills (juggling, picking pockets, etc.)
is a jack of all trades. If the skills are in intellectual matters, that person is a polymath.

Answer (score 0):

How about *versatile*?

From the Oxford dictionnary:

> Able to adapt or be adapted to many different functions or activities.
>
> > He was *versatile* enough to play on either wing.

which seems to be pretty close of fwhat you're asking. However, it does not really imply that the subject has a particular talent for different skills.

Alternatively, there is *multitalented*, which seems to be a neologism. Always from Oxford dictionnary:

> Having many skills or talents.
>
> > A multitalented musician and songwriter.

Comment: I'm hoping to convert it into a title. Eg, a prestidigitator

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: I don't think titles can be anything but creative.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam Webster's Dictionary lists two senses of the word, [***Ambidextrous***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambidextrous), which seem to apply to your scenario.

1. Unusually skilful
2. Characterized by duplicity

Answer (score 0):

Since *"jack of all trades* could also describe someone who is a competent barber/plumber/jockey/chef, it would be more precise to call your talented friend a ***"flimflam artist.***